# Updating a mySQL database with one button

Tags: php, html, mysql, button, mysqli

I'm attempting to add votes on posts in mySQL with a button. Click the button, and +1 is added to the votes table. Obviously, a form needs more than an input button. How do I specify what I am adding?

I want my vote to be assigned to the correct row in the HTML table:

```
<td> ' . $row['votes_total'].'
<br><form method="post">
<button type="submit" value="$vote_result">Vote</button>
</form></td>
</tr>';
```

I know what I've currently got there is wrong, I'm just lost here. I'm attempting to submit it with this, which is also probably wrong:

```
$votes = $_POST['votes'];
if (!empty ($_POST)) { 
    $vote_query = "UPDATE votes SET votes=votes+1 WHERE votes='$votes'";
    print $vote_query;                                                      
    $vote_result = mysqli_query ($link, $vote_query);
}
```

Let me know if I'm close to being on the right track, thanks.

Comment: From where you're getting this `$_POST['votes']`? You don't have any input field named *name*.

Comment: I'm wondering this as well. How is it supposed to know where it's drawing the data from?

Comment: What does `$vote_result` contain? Also, do you have any id value associated to each row?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <td> ' . $row['votes_total'].'
<br><form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="votes" value="$vote_result" />
<button type="submit">Vote</button>
                            </form></td>
                            </tr>';

...
```